# Pass by vs. walk past

Tags: verbs

What is the difference between **walk past** and **pass by?**

[image]

> The two men often **walk past** by the eiffel tower.

Vs.

> The two men often **pass by** the eiffel tower.

Or they both the same? Any subtleties or any sort...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would not say “walk past by”, just “walk past”. This means to encounter something on the way while walking and then keep going away from it. “Pass by” has pretty much the same meaning but could refer to other means of travel- you could pass something by while running, driving, riding in a train or boat, etc. It also means to encounter something along a path and then keep going (but not necessarily by walking).

Answer (score 3):

**Walk past** (no by after that; not necessarily wrong, but unnatural) specifies the manner in which they pass - they are walking, not running, cycling or driving (etc.).

**Pass by** *in that context* means largely the same, but without specifying the manner in which they are travelling. It can carry the connotation of doing so casually, without being too deliberate about what they are passing. *Walk past* would not suggest they were being deliberate about it, but wouldn't mean they weren't, either. However, that implication is not reliable.

*Pass by* is also used idiomatically for other things, sometimes abstract or metaphorical.

> I never had a tamagotchi. That trend passed me by.
>
> Just sit back, and let time pass by.